# Error while running rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I got this error:

```
git://github.com/rails/prototype-rails.git (at 4.2) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
```

When I run this:

```
sudo rake crons:generate
```

From what does this come? And how can I solve this?

I have defined this in the gemfile:

```
gem 'prototype-rails', :github => 'rails/prototype-rails', :branch => '4.2'
```

Everything else works fine except for the cronjob.

This is the GemFile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
gem "airbrake"
#gem "mysql"
#gem 'mysql2',  '~>0.3.7'
gem 'mysql2', '~>0.3.9'
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'newrelic_rpm', :group => [:production, :staging]
gem "xml-simple", :require => "xmlsimple"
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.0"
gem "json", '1.7.7'
gem "default_value_for"
gem "whenever"
gem 'charlock_holmes'
gem 'rails_autolink'
gem 'mocha'
gem 'daemons'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.2"
gem 'thread_safe', '0.3.5'
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.1.2'

group :development do
 gem 'capistrano'
 gem 'capistrano-ext'
 gem 'railroady'

end
```

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` yet?

Comment: sorry forgetten to mention. Yes of course done it severel times. also deleted the Gemfile.lock several times

Comment: What's your rails  version?

Comment: I've got Rails 4.2 ... I have uprgaded from 3.2.12

Comment: `prototype-rails` mentions that it might not work on rails 4.1 and above. try reverting to a lower rails version and see what happens. if that makes it work, then the rails version is breaking things.

Comment: hmmm ... do you know whats going on when I delete the gem? what does prototype do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77129/discussion-between-micah-and-felix).